# Path to resources inside custom module

Tags: html, angular, image, assets

I have a module:

Obs.: It's not the root module

```
my-module
├── components
|   └── my-component
|        └── my-component.html
└── images
    └── my-image.png
```

I am trying to set the path to "my-image.png" inside "my-component.html".

I have already tried to following ways:

```
    img src="./images/my-image.png"
    img src="../images/my-image.png"
    img src="/images/my-image.png"
```

But when i serve my app, angular resolves my paths to:

```
    localhost:4200/./images/my-image.png
    localhost:4200/../images/my-image.png
    localhost:4200/images/my-image.png
```

I want angular to resolve my path relative to the module where my html file is inside.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add your images folder to the assets in your angular.json:

```
"assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              {
                "glob": "*.{png,jpg,gif,svg}",
                "input": "src/app/path-to-your-module/images",
                "output": "your-module/images"
              }

            ],
```

This matches all png,jpg,gif and svg files in your images directory.
And outputs them to `your-module/images/`. To use your images inside your module use:

```
<img src="your-module/images/your-image.png">
```

By using a object instead of a string you can specify the output directory. Otherwise you would have to use the complete path to your module in the img tag.

Comment: Worked for me! I had to run "ng serve" again after applying that change.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this by adding path in angular.json like below

```
 "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "my-module/images"
            ],
```

and in img try this

```
img src="images/my-image.png"
```

Hope useful